# Trouble integrating Slim php and client side application

Tags: php, url-routing, slim

I have a [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) application with following structure

```
project_root/
  index.php
  Slim
  Client
    index.html
    scripts
    styles
    partials
```

I need to do the following:

1. Slim/PHP application should act as a `rest server` that responds in `json` for urls starting with `/apis`
2. Other urls should be redirected to `Client` and resources viz. styles,scripts should be served statically.
3. Client application is an independent application. (in this case an angular application)

index.php contents are like

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());

// Routes

$app->get('/apis/register',function(){
  echo "apis/register";
});
```

The following route renders `index.html` page. initial page of my angular application.
But styles and scripts are not getting served.

I get 404 Not Found for styles and scripts.

```
$app->get('/:route',function($route) use ($app) {
  $app->config('templates.path', './Client/'); 
  $app->render('index.html');       
})->conditions(array("route" => "(index|style)"));
```

***How can i host `styles` and `scripts` that are used by client application?***

May be through some Slim route(preferred) or through apache configuration

In **rails** we can write following routes.

```
  match "/styles" => redirect("/")
  match "/partials" => redirect("/")
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like `/*` is not yet supported in Slim  or its missed in documentation.

Like in node.js we do,

```
{
    path: '/*',
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    middleware: [function(req, res) {           
        res.render('index');
    }]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Slim has some kind of bug for redirecting to non-existing sub directory .htacess rewrites. I had a similar problem. I actually created the sub-directory and made the .htaccess to direct all API calls to specific sub directory and avoid App directory.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421302/how-to-mod-rewrite-php-slim-url-to-sub-directory). It eventually solved my problem.

UPDATE: have a look at [this](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/1083-redirecting-to-slim-app-in-subdirectory) at the Slim Help Thread. They had this issue indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these instructions (Apache Module mod_rewrite) in your .htaccess file to only send non-existing files to Slim.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: I have these configs in my .htaccess

Comment: Do you get 404 error while directly trying to access these static files through the browser ?