# Host a Slim microsite in a subdirectory

Tags: php, slim

Is there a nice and supported way to define routes like this:

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
});
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
});
```

... and get them work as expected no matter the location of the `index.php` routing file?

E.g. if `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `C:\Projects\Playground` (`http://playground.example.com`) and my router file is located at `C:\Projects\Playground\PHP\Slim\foo\bar\index.php` (`http://playground.example.com/PHP/Slim/foo/bar`) I'd like `http://playground.example.com/PHP/Slim/foo/bar/hello/world!` to match `'/hello/{name}'`.

(Every other file belonging to Slim would be somewhere else, let's say `C:\Libraries\Slim`, and should be irrelevant to this question.)

With *nice and supported* I mean not this:

```
$uri_prefix = complex_function_to_calculate_it($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], __DIR__);
$app->get($uri_prefix . '/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
});
```

Slim 3 uses [nikic/fast-route](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) but I couldn't find any hint.

Comment: This seems like a strange folder structure. Are you using Composer? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145717/283078

Comment: @cmbuckley This particular layout is a playground site I use for quick testing (though I'm interested in generic solutions I could use in real life cases). I use Composer and I'm not interested in MVC right now (a PSR-7 microframework is better suited for my current needs).

Comment: In that case, the `public` directory should be your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: @cmbuckley That would dump the rest of the site in a black hole.

Comment: Your source files should not be public facing code, so you should probably sit all your current public-facing content in `C:\Projects\Test\public` and update the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` accordingly. You can then use URL rewriting or symbolic linking to send all URLs beginning with your desired subdirectory to the Slim application (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421302/how-to-mod-rewrite-php-slim-url-to-sub-directory)

Comment: @cmbuckley Yes, I know how to install a Slim project as standalone site. This question is about sharing the same virtual host (using Apache terminology).

Comment: As I say - a URL rewrite might be the best way to go here, but you're making some initial errors up front (such as putting non-public code in a public-facing directory) that you should address first before continuing.

Comment: @cmbuckley I've edited my question and rewritten path names, I hope it's clear now what it's all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well... If it isn't supported out of the box, I guess it's better to just not complicate it too much and make it a parameter:

```
define('ROUTE_PREFIX', '/PHP/Slim/foo/bar');
$app->get(ROUTE_PREFIX . '/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
});
```

After all, writing generic code that calculates it dynamically under all circumstances is too much of a burden, esp. when you can have endless factors like symlinks or Apache aliases.

The parameter should of course be defined with the rest of your site settings (either `src/settings.php` if you use [Slim Skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton), `.env` if you use [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)... whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Besides creating .htaccess file in the subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

you need to either configure web server or slim:

**Solution 1 (configure apache):**

On debian 9 open the following file:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Once opened, modify

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

into

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and then restart the apache to apply the changes:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

**Solution 2 (configure slim):**

Attach this:

```
// Activating routes in a subfolder
$container['environment'] = function () {
    $scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = dirname(dirname($scriptName)) . '/' . basename($scriptName);
    return new Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER);
};
```

Note that you'll need to use subdir name in the routes, e.g. /subdir/ for home, or some specific route: /subdir/auth/signup

Answer (score 0):

You could nest all of your routes inside of a wrapper group in Slim, for which the path pattern is determined based on the `$_SERVER` variable:

```php
$app = Slim\Factory\AppFactory::create();
$app->group(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), function($subdirectory) {
    $subdirectory->group('/api/v1', $function($api) {
        // define routes as usual, e.g...
        $api->get('/foo/{foo:[0-9]+}', function($req, $res) {
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

A little pre-processing of the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` variable lets you do other things -- detect that your API is nested inside a directory named API and don't append another API to the route pattern, for example.